# Editing an Answer With "Best Practices"

Tags: discussion, edits

I have had an edit that changes the code example "Modifying to the some best practice in NodeJS" on an answer that is not specific to NodeJS, but that could well be used on NodeJS.

Is this kind of edit acceptable, because what is "best practice" for NodeJS may not be what JavaScript developers follow?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26502275/revisions

Shouldn't the code be left as it is, and programmers can adapt it to their specific situation as required?

Comment: The code should be the code you're having a problem with. Nothing else. If your edited code is still causing you the same issue, it's fine. In that edit I would say it's not fine purely because they've changed `==` to `===` which could affect the output.

Comment: as far as code changes goes..it is entirely on OP. Editing should be limited to formatting.If OP is overlooking something better to alert them with a comment.That edit is not fine IMHO.

Comment: That user is confusing "what the examples I've seen in Node.js do" with "best practices". Just because a lot of people use arrow functions does not mean that they should always be used.